# Here default tilelayer styles

Tags: here-api

We are upgrading from v2 of tilelayer to v3.  In v2 we had access to 30 default schemes/styles from Here.

1. normal.day
2. hybrid.day
3. normal.traffic.day
4. etc.

It looks like in v3 we only have access to 4.

1. explore.day
2. explore.night
3. explore.satellite.day
4. satellite.day

Is it possible to get or create the other styles, particularly the traffic styles?

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely related to the version you are using:

If you have upgraded to version 3.0, you can use this tool:
https://demo.support.here.com/examples/v3/mrs_options

Where you will be able to change to the exact schema you are looking for and play with the parameters such as "Tile Type".

But, if you are using version 3.1, you must check the following tool:
https://demo.support.here.com/examples/v3.1/simple_raster_map

Where you can see the implementation of these "schemes" and "styles" is a bit different, this is by selecting the view you are looking for.

We hope this is helpful for you.

Just a quick note:
This is only available for users who have a developer here account.

Comment: Part of this process is that we will be migrating from developer here account to platform here account.  We have our Here account through Korem (reseller) and we are waiting on them to actually do that migration.

Comment: We are using https://maps.hereapi.com/v3/{resource}/mc/{z}/{x}/{y}/{format}?apiKey={apiKey}&style={style}&size={tileResolution} for the API call to get map tiles.  The style parameter would be replaced with one of the styles we have access to.  According to a call to https://maps.hereapi.com/v3/info? we only have the 4 styles that I mentioned above.  In v2, they were called schemes instead of styles and we had access to 30 of them.  From what I've been seeing, it appears the official release of v3 has been delayed.  Do you plan on releasing more styles in the future?